Adding search fields to dependent dropdowns + having those dropdowns display text (2-in-1!)
ETA: I've added [SPAM MARK PROTECTION] to some links within previously attempted solutions - hopefully it's clear enough that that.. isn't part of the code, but sorry for the awkwardness!
I have a first website project where I have two dependent dropdown menus that I would like to 1) add a search option to each of and 2) have display text based on the combined selections.
My current code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
    {
        switch (listindex)
        {
        case "salesforce" :
            document.getElementById("end").options[0]=new Option("End","");
            document.getElementById("end").options[1]=new Option("Slack","slack");
            document.getElementById("end").options[2]=new Option("Google Sheets","googlesheets");
            break;
        case "slack" :
            document.getElementById("end").options[0]=new Option("End","");
            document.getElementById("end").options[1]=new Option("Salesforce","salesforce");
            document.getElementById("end").options[2]=new Option("Google Sheets","googlesheets");
            break;
        case "googlesheets" :
            document.getElementById("end").options[0]=new Option("End","");
            document.getElementById("end").options[1]=new Option("Salesforce","salesforce");
            document.getElementById("end").options[2]=new Option("Slack","slack");
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <h2>Dependent dropdowns</h2>
    <div class="category_div" id="category_div">
        <select id="source" name="source" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="start">Start</option>
        <option value="salesforce">Salesforce</option>
        <option value="slack">Slack</option>
        <option value="googlesheets">Google Sheets</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        document.write('<select name="end" id="end"><option value="">End</option></select>')
        </script>
        <noscript>
        <select id="end" name="end">
            <option value="slack">Slack</option>
            <option value="googlesheets">Google Sheets</option>
        </select>
        </noscript>
    </div>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>

For reference, this is adapted from this Stack Overflow response - didn't choose the highest rated since I'm a beginner to JS with only 'old social media profile editing'-lead HTML knowledge, and this option was the easiest to parse for me and to know I would be able to build on easily when adding more menu options after this 'get it to work' stage. Which is to say, I'm not opinionated about the use of <option> over <li> or anything else beyond 1) I had a clear enough understanding of how to utalise this example beyond the copy-paste stage and 2) it was the first I tried to start adapting that worked as expected.
Attempts to add search:
I attempted adapting the snippet in this response since it's the exact thing I needed and seemed like it should 'mash together' easily for me; I incorporated it like this:
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('select').selectize({
          sortField: 'text'
      });
  });

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
    {
        switch (listindex)
        {
        case "salesforce" :
            document.getElementById("end").options[0]=new Option("End","");
            document.getElementById("end").options[1]=new Option("Slack","slack");
            document.getElementById("end").options[2]=new Option("Google Sheets","googlesheets");
            break;
        case "slack" :
            document.getElementById("end").options[0]=new Option("End","");
            document.getElementById("end").options[1]=new Option("Salesforce","salesforce");
            document.getElementById("end").options[2]=new Option("Google Sheets","googlesheets");
            break;
        case "googlesheets" :
            document.getElementById("end").options[0]=new Option("End","");
            document.getElementById("end").options[1]=new Option("Salesforce","salesforce");
            document.getElementById("end").options[2]=new Option("Slack","slack");
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https:/[SPAM MARK PREVENTION]/ajax.googleapis.[SPAM MARK PREVENTION]com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https:/[SPAM MARK PREVENTION]/cdnjs.cloudflare.[SPAM MARK PREVENTION]com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-+C0A5Ilqmu4QcSPxrlGpaZxJ04VjsRjKu+G82kl5UJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:/[SPAM MARK PREVENTION]/cdnjs.cloudflare.[SPAM MARK PREVENTION]com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" integrity="sha256-ze/OEYGcFbPRmvCnrSeKbRTtjG4vGLHXgOqsyLFTRjg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <h2>Dependent dropdowns</h2>
    <div class="category_div" id="category_div">
        <select id="source" name="source" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="start">Start</option>
        <option value="salesforce">Salesforce</option>
        <option value="slack">Slack</option>
        <option value="googlesheets">Google Sheets</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        document.write('<select name="end" id="end"><option value="">End</option></select>')
        </script>
        <noscript>
        <select id="end" name="end">
            <option value="slack">Slack</option>
            <option value="googlesheets">Google Sheets</option>
        </select>
        </noscript>
    </div>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>


...and it produces the same result as just the menus alone. I assume having multiple menus at play may mean I would have to 'link' these additions to both, but I have no idea how to. I also thought a lack of CSS could be at play, but by my understanding the stylesheet included should be handling that? Or the not working could be explained by this response being five years old and the linked scripts no longer functioning as expected. I've also placed the additional scripts above the current ones rather than below, and added what seemed to be a missing end tag on the <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:/[SPAM MARK PREVENTION]/cdnjs.cloudflare.[SPAM MARK PREVENTION]com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" integrity="sha256-ze/OEYGcFbPRmvCnrSeKbRTtjG4vGLHXgOqsyLFTRjg=" crossorigin="anonymous" /> line - no dice.
With what I've not tried, most of the solutions I'm finding in general are based on <li> over <option>, which I only haven't changed it to because I don't know how to do so whilst maintaining the dependent nature of the menus - I'd be wildly grateful to anyone inclined to give me an overhaul of the original to work with <li> to then try those solutions, but I'm not annoying enough to ask for that specifically. I've also seen references to form actions like in this response, but I have no idea how to implement it if it would work.
Attempts to display text based on combined results:
(*my specific end goal would ideally actually be a table - happy to handle this myself in CSS or HTML, but just a note that 'pure text' it not a goal despite the shorthand implying it)
I do want this to be a 'unique' text based on combined results rather than fill-in-the-gaps - this project is actually a ThisToThat-like for workflow automation software, so a selection of "Salesforce" + "Slack" will in the end display something like this:
| Zapier    | Add contact on Salesforce       | Send message to Slack channel
| Zapier    | Contact phone number is updated | Update Slack profile info
| Make      | Add contact on Salesforce       | Send message to Slack channel
The solution in this CodeProject question seems viable, since adding an onchange state is straightforward:
<script language="JavaScript">

var DivTxt = new Array()
DivTxt[0] = "Please Select Priority"
DivTxt[1] = "Priority Low: The selection is Low"
DivTxt[2] = "Priority Normal: The selection is Normal"
DivTxt[3] = "Priority High: The selection is High"
DivTxt[3] = "Priority Critical: The selection is Critical"

function getText(slction){
txtSelected = slction.selectedIndex;
document.getElementById('textDiv').innerHTML = DivTxt[txtSelected];
}
</script>


<Select class="body_text" name="critical" onchange="getText(this)">
<option value="Select"> Select </option>
   <option value="LOW"> Low </option>
   <option value="NORMAL"> Normal </option>
   <option value="HIGH"> High </option>
   <option value="CRITICAL"> Critical </option>      
</select>
<div id="textDiv" style="color:Green; font-family:Calibri; font-size:small; font-weight:bold"> </div>

...but I don't know how to account for both selections in doing so.
For ease of anyone who does look at this, here's some placeholder text for my current menu combinations:

Text for Salesforce and Slack
Text for Salesforce and Google Sheets
Text for Slack and Salesforce
Text for Slack and Google Sheets
Text for Google Sheets and Salesforce
Text for Google Sheets and Slack

It felt like making these two separate questions in a row would push this from 'asking for advice' to 'asking someone to do my homework', but there's a good chance that a 2-in-1 is less kosher for that same reason - if so, sorry for the first question faux pas! But any suggestions on how to get the solutions I've already identified working would be extremely appreciated ✨ I would also appreciate the suggestions being as vanilla as possible!

What do you want to fix first and where is it in your question? (because its a tad bit verbose)

@Getset tad bit verbose is a fair read - taking the code under "The current menus:" and having text displayed based on the combined selection as explained under "For displaying text* based on combined results:" is the main want, taking that OG code and adding search to the menus as explained under "For search:" is a nice to have. The code under both those sections are potential solutions I've come across that I don't know how to make work (if they would work) ETA: somehow through my lurking I've never registered the lack of inline images - I'll make some formatting edits for clarity too.

Do you have any errors? Some of the code e.g. document.getElementById("end").options[0]=new Option("End",""); I've never seen written as such. Does it work? You can check for javascript errors by opening your browser dev tools, and navigating to the console pane.

@getset no errors showing in dev tools, and that first block of code is working as expected. I'm not trying to fix anything about my current code but rather am looking for insight how to add the things I've mentioned to it, but I am happy to use a 'rebuilt' version of the cascading menus code if that then makes it easier to 'extend' in these ways.

To match the edits for clarity I've made, the clarification I made in the previous comment would be: my aim here is taking the code under "My current code:" and having text displayed based on the combined selection as explained under "Attempts to display text based on combined results:", as well as taking that OG code and adding search to the menus.
